# How do I find out what my.cnf is being used?

Tags: mysql, linux, my.cnf

With MySQL, a my.cnf can be used specify configuration properties. MySQL may look in a variety of places to find this file, and if it doesn't find it may use built-in defaults.

How do you know what my.cnf is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysqld --help --verbose | grep -B 1 cnf
```

Beneath the "Default options are read from the following files in the given order:" line will be the locations MySQL is looking for the my.cnf file.